# Why Python numpy is not respecting the provided delimiter

Tags: python, numpy, fixed-width

New learner here. I'm trying to write a fixed-width file in Python. I did a lot of google search to find a module the can help achieve the goal. I'm attempting with `numpy`. The function is not respecting any of the provided delimiters.

## Code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
  "Make": ['BMW', 'Toyota', 'Dodge', 'Honda'],
  "Model": ['X5', 'Camry', 'Caravan', 'Accord'],
  "Weight": [1020.25, 950.98, 1235.37, 940.9],
  "Year": [2021, 2023, 2019, 2014]
}

#load data into a DataFrame object:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

with open('test_output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
            fmt = '%-6s %-7s %-7s %-4s'
            np.savetxt(outfile, df.values,delimiter='*', fmt=fmt) #Testing with any delimiter
```

## Code Output

[Code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRcJS.png)

## Desired Output

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6raa.png)

My desired output should not contain any spaces between the columns. I attempted `delimiter=''` and `delimiter=' '`. The function is not respecting any delimiter when I provide an `fmt`.

I'm open to use different modules.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You have spaces in your `fmt` string. Remove them, and try again.

Comment: You're explicitly putting the spaces in with `fmt = '%-6s %-7s %-7s %-4s'`. If you use `fmt = '%-6s%-7s%-7s%-4s'`, the spaces will not be there

Comment: Note that [the documentation for `savetxt` - `fmt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) states: "... or a multi-format string, e.g. ‘Iteration %d – %10.5f’, in which case delimiter is ignored". Always carefully read the documentation for functions etc you use.

Comment: Removing the spaces from  `fmt ` did the job. Thank you :)